# is there a way wherein I can run the api until certain conditions are met in Jmeter?

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

I am currently trying to run the test plan for cab booking scenario in Jmeter.I need to run the 'Events fetching' API until the ride status is either COMPLETED or NO_AVAILABLE_DRIVER.I have tried using the while controller with the condition :

```
${__javaScript("${eventStatus}"!="NO_AVAILABLE_DRIVER"||,"${eventStatus}"!="COMPLETED")}
```

But ,the controller  enters infinite loop.
Can someone please help me with this issue?

If controller doesn't give the required results as well.

Comment: Why you have a comma?

Answer (score 0):

As per [While Controller's](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) documentation:

> The condition can be any variable or function that eventually evaluates to the string "false". This allows the use of [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3), [__groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function, properties or variables as needed.

So I think you need to amend your condition to be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('eventStatus') != 'NO_AVAILABLE_DRIVER' && vars.get('eventStatus') != 'COMPLETED',)}
```

where `vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information.